# 'Where-in' query in postgresql for two different queries showing same result

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I have the active record assosciation relation as follows.

```
@tasks =  #<ActiveRecord::AssociationRelation [#<Task id: 3130, title: "Commit to at least one small win today", content: "When I check-in on the app it lets me acknowledge m...",created_at: "2016-01-13 01:36:15", updated_at: "2016-01-13 04:47:57", state: "active", #<Task id: 3131, title: "Purposefully walk 3 minutes ", content: "More than just my ordinary day, I choose 5 minutes ...", created_at: "2016-01-13 04:52:32", updated_at: "2016-01-13 04:56:22", state: "active", #<Task id: 3132, title: "1km Walk or Run by Sunday", content: "I pick a direction, start with a 10 minute warm up,...", created_at: "2016-01-13 04:56:05", updated_at: "2016-01-13 04:56:05", state: "active",#<Task id: 3249, title: "1km Walk or Run by Wednesday", content: "I pick a direction, start with a 10 minute warm up,...", created_at: "2016-01-24 23:23:34", updated_at: "2016-01-24 23:23:34", state: "active"]> 


@array = []

@tasks.each do |task|
if (condition)
  @array << task.id
end  

@tasks = @tasks.where.not('tasks.id in (?)',@array)
```

If I get any non empty value in @array, 
 the above condition is working fine. 
If I get @array = [] i,e empty array,
@tasks = @tasks.where.not('tasks.id in (?)',@array) is not giving me correct result.

Also, @tasks = @tasks.where('tasks.id in (?)',@array), this condition by removing 'not' giving the same result when not is present when the array is []

```
 @habits = @habits.where.not('habits.id in (?)',@id_s)  ====> output => []
 @habits = @habits.where('habits.id in (?)',@id_s)  ====> output => []

They both are returning same optput if @id_s is []
```

Why these queries are returning the same value for two different conditions?

Answer (score 0):

If your Rails version is up to date you should switch to the hash notation, which handles all special cases like empty arrays for you:

```
@tasks = @tasks.where.not(id: @array)
```